# How can I change the frequency (Fs) of a sound at a push of a button?

Tags: matlab

I call an audio player in one function along with a variable

```
global ap1
global doublespeed
ap1 = audioplayer(y,Fs);
doublespeed = Fs*2;
```

I have another function which is a button, where I would like the frequency to multiply by 2, then play the sound sample.

```
global ap1
global doublespeed
playblocking(ap1,doublespeed);
```

This code plays the sound, but it seems to skip to 2 seconds into the song. If I have the frequency change for when I call the `audioplayer`, it tends to work, but doesn't suit what I want to make. Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: I can't give you an exact answer, but I really discourage you from using global variables - there was always a faster and more reliable way in my use cases. When creating GUIs, you can e.g. save variables in the `handles` structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `playblocking` doesn't change the frequency.  Did you read the description of that function?  It specifically says the second input is start, stop.  Which is exactly what you got.

You need to use `audioplayer` to set the the audio object to twice the frequency.

```
load handel;
p = audioplayer(y, Fs);
play(p);
p2 = audioplayer(y, Fs * 2);
play(p2);
```

If the problem is that you don't want the samples to overlap then you use `playblocking` instead of `play`.  For example.

```
load handel;
p = audioplayer(y, Fs);
p2 = audioplayer(y, Fs * 2);
play(p);
play(p2); % the sounds will overlap

playblocking(p);
playblocking(p2); % the sounds will not overlap
```